# Recreating audio filter curves in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

If I wanted to program curves of various audio filters, what tools should I use to construct them in canvas?

http://raider.mountunion.edu/~miskeljp/ds/resources/filters/filter_types.jpg

My ideas are:

- quadraticCurveTo
- bezierCurveTo
- custom curve using Math.sin

Since I am still lacking experience I hope that someone could tell me what the best aproach would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic, Bezier, and sine curves won't likely fit a filter curve well. They can be wrangled into place, but I don't recommend it.

If these curves are supposed to be dynamic, I recommend finding the actual functions for the filters and using lineTo(x,y) as many times as you see fit.

If you have the mathematical function programmed into a javascript function, you can then do the following.

```
context.beginPath();
for(var i = startX; i<endX; i++)
    context.lineTo(i, myCurve(i));
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();
```

The only reason not to do this is if you are worried about performance issues or if your canvas is very large.

If either of those is the case, you should probably use a pre-computed curve. Bezier curves work well for this type of work.

If you need your curve dynamic and you have the aforementioned performance issues, you'll need to find a mathematician and figure out how to map independent functions to Bezier curves. That can be done, but it takes a fair amount of algebra.

Comment: I did find a formula for the high pass filter but I dont think any of those help in this context https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter

Comment: I think you are right. This is a large amount of work. I think beziercurves are the closest I can get then. It wont be precise but will at least look similar. At least high and low pass filters can be emulated. Changing the Q (Band width) is a bit hard to program dynamically though. Somewhat emulating curves with sin works well though http://jsfiddle.net/5v4judqf/5/ especially changing the Q (band width)